# How to deal with Time Conflicts?

Tags: php, javascript

I am facing a problem to deal with time conflicts. I am creating a system where users will have to insert start time and end time for two different events. like-

```
  Event-1 Day  StartTime-1 EndTime1

  Event-2 Day  StartTime-2 EndTime2
```

I have text boxes to input time. Now how to deal with this matter when any user inputs start and end time for an event that conflicts with the time of other the event? For example:

```
 Event-1  Sunday  2:30 PM 4:30 PM

 Event-2  Sunday  3:00 PM 4:00 PM
```

Would you please kindly help me, how to solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you looking to achieve this in PHP, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890585/calendar-offset-overlapping-events

Answer (score 4):

Check whether they are overlapping. Using `Date.parse()` and just comparing numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/VGyRW/1/.

```
var i1 = Date.parse($('#i1').val()); // this is jQuery but comes down to the value of first select
var i2 = Date.parse($('#i2').val());
var i3 = Date.parse($('#i3').val());
var i4 = Date.parse($('#i4').val());

if(i1 > i4 && i2 > i4 || i1 < i3 && i2 < i3) {
    // begin and end of first must be both larger than end of second,
    // or both smaller than begin of second
    alert('ok');
} else { 
    alert('not ok');
}
```

Comment: Open your console? With 13k rep I'd image that your JS doesn't need much debugging.

Comment: @pimvdb. Thanks for your reply. But the java-script is not working well. In the jsfiddle please try to input 2:30 for #i1, 3:30 for #i2, 3:35 for #i3 and 4:00 for #i4. I am sure it will say "not ok". But actually as you can see.. it is okay. :) Thanks again for you reply

Comment: @Srijon: It works for me. Note that it uses the new HTML5 `<input type="datetime">` element. Instead of typing, you should use the arrows on the right to alter the value. Perhaps your browser does not support it. I use Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with that. Can't you imagine user have party from 1:00 AM to 8:00 AM and another event sleeping from 6:00AM to 11:00 AM?

So answer: Do not solve it. It isn't a problem

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the time from HH:MM format to HH:MM:SS. In other words, add the seconds to it too.